# Sobre fechas y formatos Datetime en Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

Debo hacer un programa que pregunte una fecha en formato dd/mm/aaaa y muestre por pantalla
la misma fecha en formato "dd del  del año aaaa" donde  es el nombre del mes pero con letras.

Lo he resuelto con un **diccionario** tal que así:

```
meses = {1:'enero', 2:'febrero', 3:'marzo', 4:'abril', 5:'mayo', 6:'junio', 7:'julio', 8:'agosto', 9:'septiembre', 10:'octubre', 11:'noviembre', 12:'diciembre'}
fecha = input('Introduce una fecha en formato dd/mm/aaaa: ')
fecha = fecha.split('/')
print(fecha[0], 'de', meses[int(fecha[1])], 'de', fecha[2])
```

Funciona prefectamente y está dentro de lo que me pide el profe. OK. Pero me parece muy rústico, así que me puse a leer sobre la lib datetime, y me gustaría hacer lo mismo pero con la lib nativa y sus operadores, entonces me sale una cosa así:

```
from datetime import datetime
fecha = input("Intro la fecha en formato dd/mm/aaaa: ")
salida = datetime.strftime(fecha, '%d %b %Y')
print(salida)
```

No me funciona. Y ya he probado todo lo que se me ocurre. ¿Sabeis por qué no me funciona? ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?, o ¿solo es posible hacerlo con diccionario como en el ejemplo 1?.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué no aceptas las respuestas que te han dado a tus otras preguntas?

Comment: Que eso?. Como que no lo acepto. Si hasta las voté, pero no aparece reflejado. Si te refieres a las posibles soluciones que da el sistema segun el encabezamiento, no es que lo las acepte es que no tienen mucho que ver con lo que yo pregunto salvo que estamos hablando de date y date time, el sistema te dice que otras preguntas tienen ese encabezamiento pero las lees, si las lees y no se parecen como un huevo a una castaña. Incluso las he mirado en la lista en ingles, y no cuadran...Quiza no entiendo muy bien a que te refieres.

Comment: Revisa el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). En esa página verás como se "acepta" una respuesta. Mientras no aceptes una respuesta, la pregunta seguirá abierta.

Comment: Vaya lo siento. Gracias. Todas me fueron muy útiles, pensé que sólo habia que votarlas. Ya estan aceptadas.

Comment: Si, al "aceptar" validas la respuesta. Así otros en igual situación saben que es buena y funciona.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tal y como lo tienes, te estará diciendo que strftime requiere un `datetime.date`, y lo que le estás pasando es una cadena de texto.

Primero tienes que transformar el input en una fecha con `strptime` indicándole el formato de entrada.

No es tu caso, pero con esa fecha podrías ya hacer operaciones como sumarle días, horas, etc.
O como quieres en tu caso, imprimirla con un formato específico (con `strftime`):

```
from datetime import datetime

fecha_string = input("Intro la fecha en formato dd/mm/aaaa: ") #Recibe una cadena de texto
fecha = datetime.strptime(fecha_string, '%d/%m/%Y') #Lo convierte a datetime
print(datetime.strftime(fecha, '%d %b %Y')) #Lo vuelve a convertir en texto con el formato que quieras
```

Por otro lado, los nombres de los meses te los devolverá en inglés. Si quieres que no sea así y te los imprima en español, puedes añadir antes:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES')
```

Comment: Perfecto. Son dos pasos. Yo sólo daba uno Es lógico. Gracias